# How to call function every hour? Also, how can I loop this?

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I need a simple way to call a function every 60 minutes. How can I do this? I'm making a MineCraft bukkit plugin, and this is what I have:

```
package com.webs.playsoulcraft.plazmotech.java.MineRegen;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");


    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.log.info("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        this.log.info("Plaz's Mine Regen is now enabled!");
        this.log.info("Copyright 2012 Plazmotech Co. All rights reserved.");
        this.log.info("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDisable() {
        this.log.info("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        this.log.info("Plaz's Mine Regen is now disabled!");
        this.log.info("Copyright 2012 Plazmotech Co. All rights reserved.");
        this.log.info("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    }

    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        final Action action = event.getAction();
        if (action == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Location l1 = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
        } else if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Location l2 = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to run a function I will implement every hour, how? Remember: The function will use l1, and l2. Also, how can I loop this to get every block inbetween?

Comment: First, I want to ask why you need to run a function every hour and use event function onPlayerInteract to trigger an event based on left or right click. This seems to contradict each other.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a `Timer` object and give it a `TimerTask` that performs the code you'd like to perform.

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // your code here...
    }
};

// schedule the task to run starting now and then every hour...
timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 1000*60*60);
```

If you declare `hourlyTask` within your `onPlayerInteract` function, then you can access `l1` and `l2`.  To make that compile, you will need to mark both of them as `final`.

The advantage of using a `Timer` object is that it can handle multiple `TimerTask` objects, each with their own timing, delay, etc.  You can also start and stop the timers as long as you hold on to the `Timer` object by declaring it as a class variable or something.

I don't know how to get every block in between.

Comment: I would vote to use Timer class rather than Thread, as others might. The reason is Timer uses the system timer/clock to trigger the function call. Therefore the timing should be accurate as much as possible. Whereas using threads will depend on the Java thread management and the operating system, rather complicated to predict.

Comment: @Plazmotech, You will have to add code to access the local object l1 or l2, which comes from an event based function. I'll leave it at that for now.

Answer (score 4):

Create a thread that will run forever and wakes up every hour to execute your data.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000*60*60);
                //your code here...
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: Thannks!
Syntax error on token "t", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add a semicolon at the end of `t` declaration. I already added it.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` doesn't work when using Bukkit or Spigot. The server will freeze.

Comment: @Leocat I'm not familiar with Bukkit/ Spigit server modding, but that sounds incorrect. I see no reason on how `Thread.sleep()` on a new thread will freeze the server. It shouldn't be freezing the server thread (ticking thread).

Answer (score 3):

You must use Bukkit Scheduler:

```
public void Method(){
    this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code goes here
            Method();
        }
    }, time * 20L );
}
```

You must create a method with this and there you must call the same method.

Comment: When the server is lagging < 20tps, timing is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 1):

1. The simplest way (in my opinion) is use `Thread` (the above comment has mention about it).
2. You can also use [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)  in `javax.swing.Timer`
3. But i think - as 101100 said - you can use `TimerTask`. You can check this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html)  (from IBM)

Comment: `Thread.sleep` won't work then using Bukkit/Spigot. This will cause the server to crash.