# Get application variables from within TimerTask

Tags: java

I am trying to use the Java TimerTask to perform a function every 1 minute.

I have the following code:

```
Public Class SomeClass{
String somevar = 'some text';
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
@Override
public void run () {
   I need to access the variable somevar here.
}
};
}
```

taken from here: [How to call function every hour? Also, how can I loop this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748212/how-to-call-function-every-hour-also-how-can-i-loop-this)

The problem is that in the function run(), I need to access some variables that are in the application that contains this TimerTask.

I tried the 'this' keyword, but, obvioiusly, the TimerTask is its own object, so 'this' only refers to items within the TimerTask.

Comment: What do you mean by "application variables". Please provide a small, *complete* example that illustrates what you are trying to do. By "complete", I mean that your example should also include example variables, showing what class and/or method contains them, that you need to use in the `run()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OuterClass.this.outerVariable`, but usually this isn't necessary unless the two classes, both the outer and inner classes, have variables of the same name. Otherwise outer class fields are fully accessible to inner classes.

We'll be better able to help you if you show more including your attempts and any compilation errors that they cause.

Comment: Okie. The 'Otherwise outer class fields are fully accessible' statement got me in the right direction. I was trying to use the 'this' keyword, but discovered if I leave it off, it works. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @toast, then you will want to ask a new question, and in your question tell us the details of your problem, your confusions and show your pertinent code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I saw [a thread on Bukkit](https://bukkit.org/threads/asynchronous-block-remove.202491/) (which is the API I'm using) that basically outruled using standard java.util timers and other standard java methods. Rather, I have to use the Bukkit alternative. I'll try doing that before asking another question, but thanks!